# Cocoa Resizing Two Stacked Tables

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3

I have a view with two vertically stacked Table Views. When I resize the application window, the lower table view expands. This is because I didn't specify a height for it. It has a fixed distance to the bottom of the window and a fixed distance to the table view above it. If I attempt to remove the fixed height for the upper table view, the constraints editor complains. Is it possible to have both table view expand equally when I resize the application? If not, is the possible to allow the upper table view to be resized when the application is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this as long as there is some sort of control between the two tables. A label will work fine. Using constaints:

1. For the control in between the two tables, set the Alignment constraint to "Vertically in Container. This will perfectly center the control. You can offset it above or below center by adding a positive or negative value in the combobox next to the option.
2. For the top table, pin the top of the box to the top of the window or any other place that fits your design.
3. Set the bottom constraint to some offset from the control in step 1.
4. Set the bottom constraint of the bottom table to something fixed like the bottom of the window.
5. Set the top constraint to some offset from the control in step 1.
6. Be sure not to set the height of either table.

When the window moves vertically, the control in step 1 will be moved to keep it in the center plus or minus any offset you provided. The two tables will be expanded or contracted accordingly.